# Python: XOR each character in a string

Tags: python, checksum

I'm trying to validate a checksum on a string which in this case is calculated by performing an XOR on each of the individual characters.

Given my test string:

```
check_against = "GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A"
```

I figured it would be as simple as:

```
result = 0
for char in check_against:
    result = result ^ ord(char)
```

I know the result should be `28`, however my code gives `40`.

I'm not sure what encoding the text is suppose to be in, although I've tried encoding/decoding in `utf-8` and `ascii`, both with the same result.

I implemented this same algorithm in C by simply doing an XOR over the char array with perfect results, so what am I missing?

**Edit**

So it was a little while ago that I implemented (what I thought) was the same thing in C. I knew it was in an Objective-C project but I thought I had just done it this way. Totally wrong, first there was a step where I converted the checksum string value at the end to hex like so (I'm filling some things in here so that I'm only pasting what is relevant):

```
 unsigned int checksum = 0;
 NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"26"];
 [scanner scanHexInt:&checksum];
```

Then I did the following to compute the checksum:

```
 NSString sumString = @"GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A";
 unsigned int sum = 0;
 for (int i=0;i<sumString.length;i++) {
     sum = sum ^ [sumString characterAtIndex:i];
 }
```

Then I would just compare like so:

```
 return sum == checksum;
```

Comment: Another way to check your raw values `map(ord, check_against)`, then reduce it using [`operator.xor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.xor), like so `reduce(xor, map(ord, check_against))`. In python 3 it will be [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

Comment: Depends on your python version. Make sure you loop over bytes, not Unicode.

Comment: I believe for your given example string `utf-8` vs `ascii` is a dead end because the ASCII characters have the same values in Unicode. `bytearray(check_against, encoding='utf-8') == bytearray(check_against)` returns `True` in Python 2.

Comment: Also, finally, what is your C code? I am sure the answer is `40` in base10 and `0x28` in base16. How did you generate the output `28` with C?

Comment: I just did a direct port of your Python code to C and verified that the result is correctly `40`. Link: https://ideone.com/YK8FOp

Comment: @metatoaster For completeness I'll add my C code. Also, I'm processing NMEA sentences which include the the correct checksum at the end (stripped off here), which is where I got `28` from. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Final note, seems like nobody is acknowledging this: `printf("%x\n", 40);` results in `28` being printed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as @metatoaster, @XD573, and some others in the comments have helped figure out, the issue was the difference between the result, which was base 10, and my desired solution (in base 16).

The result for the code, `40` is correct - in base 10, however my correct value I was trying to achieve, `28` is given in base 16. Simply converting the solution from base 16 to base 10, for example like so:

```
int('28', 16)
```

I get `40`, the computed result.

Answer (score 2):

```
#python3
str = "GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A"
cks = 0
i = 0

while(i<len(str)):
    cks^=ord(str[i])
    i+=1

print("hex:",hex(cks))
print("dec:",cks)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the C version as shown here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* str1="GPGLL,5300.97914,N,00259.98174,E,125926,A";
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < strlen(str1); i++) {
        sum ^= str1[i];
    }

    printf("checksum: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

And When I compiled and ran it:

```
$ gcc -o mytest mytest.c
$ ./mytest
checksum: 40
```

Which leads me to believe that the assumptions you have from your equivalent C code are incorrect.

Comment: You are correct, I just added an edit with my (Objective C, forgot it wasn't just in C) code. My current code is missing an conversion to hex for the checksum as a String I think. Also, I think there is some confusion here between the hex values and string values of the numbers in general, with myself included.